# Ionic 3, encodeURI with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I need to send a http request to firebase that has this shape

`https://db.firebaseio.com/0.json?&orderBy="name"&startAt=query&endAt=query+"\uf8ff"&limitToLast=1&print=pretty&auth=auth_token`

My problem is that when I call this request I've a 400 error in console because it replace %22 to question marks and other symbols for `\uf8ff` and I think firebase doesn't recognize that.

```
    let name = '"name"';
    let cod = '"\uf8ff"';
    let url = ('https://db.firebaseio.com/0.json?&orderBy=' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '&startAt=' + encodeURIComponent(birraName) + '&endAt=' + encodeURIComponent(birraName) + '+' + encodeURIComponent(cod) + '&limitToLast=1&print=pretty&auth=' + encodeURIComponent(this.idToken));
    let response = this.http.get(url).map(res => res.json());
    return response;
```

And then in console

> 400 Bad Request

Do you have any thougths?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes in your target string to mark string values. If you're searching for nodes starting with Marco, it should be `https://db.firebaseio.com/0.json?&orderBy="name"&startAt="Marco"&endAt="Marco\uf8ff"&limitToLast=1&print=pretty&auth=auth_token`. Note the double quotes around `"Marco"` and `"Marco\uf8ff"`.

To build these in your JavaScript:

```
var url = 'https://db.firebaseio.com/0.json';
url = url + '?orderBy="' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '"';
url = url + "&startAt="' + encodeURIComponent(birraName) + '"';
url = url + "&endAt="' + encodeURIComponent(birraName) + '\uf8ff"';
url = url + '&limitToLast=1&print=pretty';
url = url + '&auth="' + encodeURIComponent(this.idToken))+'"";
```

Template literals might also be useful to keep this readable:

```
let url = (`https://db.firebaseio.com/0.json?orderBy=${encodeURIComponent(name)}&startAt=${encodeURIComponent(birraName)}&endAt=${encodeURIComponent(birraName)}${encodeURIComponent(cod)}&limitToLast=1&print=pretty&auth=${encodeURIComponent(this.idToken))}`;
```

Comment: thanks man but now I've a 401 unauthorized with "error" : "Failed to validate signature.". But I retrieve the user token and put it in "this.idToken" at the end of the code